# Tried to register two views with the same name RCTScrollView

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, iphone, react-native

i try to run my react native app to ios but i got this error, while in android the app work just fine, do someone know about this ?

xcode 11.5,
rn 0.61.5,
using react native cli

i already search on several site but dont seem find any solution, here the screen shoot :

[image]

```
"dependencies": {
"@microsoft/signalr": "^3.1.3",
"@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.7.1",
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.2.1",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.5",
"@react-native-community/picker": "^1.6.1",
"@react-native-community/viewpager": "3.3.0",
"@sentry/react-native": "^1.4.1",
"axios": "^0.19.1",
"color": "^3.1.2",
"ellipsize": "^0.1.0",
"form-data": "^3.0.0",
"google-translate": "^3.0.0",
"i18n-js": "^3.5.1",
"intl": "^1.2.5",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"moment-range": "^4.0.2",
"numeral": "^2.0.6",
"opentok-react-native": "^0.12.2",
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-cookies": "^0.1.1",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-amazing-cropper": "^0.1.1",
"react-native-biometrics": "^2.1.4",
"react-native-camera": "^3.17.0",
"react-native-collapsible": "^1.5.1",
"react-native-daterange-picker": "^1.1.3",
"react-native-device-info": "^5.5.3",
"react-native-file-picker": "0.0.19",
"react-native-geocoder": "^0.5.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.3",
"react-native-image-crop-tools": "^1.3.4",
"react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.0",
"react-native-localize": "^1.4.0",
"react-native-location": "^2.5.0",
"react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
"react-native-onesignal": "^3.6.3",
"react-native-overlay-section": "0.1.13",
"react-native-paper": "3.4.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
"react-native-responsive-screen": "1.4.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "0.6.2",
"react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.22",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
"react-native-webview": "8.1.1",
"react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.0.4",
"react-navigation-tabs": "^2.7.0",
"react-redux": "^7.1.3",
"reanimated-bottom-sheet": "1.0.0-alpha.18",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
"sendbird": "3.0.117",
"styled-components": "^4.4.1",
"throttle-debounce": "^2.1.0",
"validator": "^12.1.0"
```

},

Comment: try to rebuild your app

Comment: already try that, clean, rebuild, clean, rebuild but no result

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the `react-native-gesture-handler` package.

Did you import it in your code ? If yes, try to remove the import and do a `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.

If this doesn't work, try to update it (Latest version at the moment is ^1.6.1) in your package.json.

Comment: already try update gesture handler, still same. while removing package gesture handler bring to another error about react-navigation dependency

Answer (score 0):

sorry just found the problem, in my app there are custom native library that use scroll view in folder src, that causing register view two times.